# Getting Canada Post Shipping warning (REST + PHP)

Tags: php

When I am sending Transmit Shipment Request to canada Post Shipping Server then it is giving me warning message "postal-zip-code value is not a valid instance of type".

My Transmit Shipment Request XML is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><transmit-set xmlnssi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/manifest" ><group-ids><group-id>ACCOUNTGROUPID</group-id></group-ids><requested-shipping-point>MYREQUESTSHIPPINGPOINT</requested-shipping-point><detailed-manifests>true</detailed-manifests><method-of-payment>Account</method-of-payment><manifest-address><manifest-company>COMPANY</manifest-company><phone-number>123456</phone-number><address-details><address-line-1>PACIFIC COAST HWY</address-line-1><city>MALIBU</city><prov-state>CA(For California)</prov-state><postal-zip-code>90265</postal-zip-code></address-details></manifest-address></transmit-set>
```

Please help me out.

Thanks,

Comment: What is this?  Where are you sending this XML?

Comment: Have you tried with other zip codes? Maybe a Canadian zip code

Comment: Well, for Canadian zip code, its working. I want to do it for International Zip Codes.

Answer (score 1):

What your xml is saying is that you intend to transmit shipments on a group of shipments where the from address is in California.

Something tells me that's not what you want.

If you are shipping from California to Canada, you'll need to use the USPS and they will hand off to Canada Post.

If you are shipping from Canada to California, you'll need to specify the destination address in California in your createShipments() call and the address information you supply in your transmitShipments() xml should be where you plan to ship from (which is either the address of your warehouse if Canada Post is going to pick up the shipments or the address of the post office where you plan to drop your shipments off with Canada Post).